# Get values and ids of all span elements inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get all span elements inside the form. The span elements are turning into input text fields and become editable. When you click away they are turning back into span elements. I will attached fiddle live example.
I gave it a go but the problem is that I am getting both ids but only value of the first span element.

Here is my html:

```
<span name="inputEditableTest" class="pztest" id="inputEditableTest" data-editable="">First Element</span>

<span name="inputEditableTest2" class="pztest" id="inputEditableTest2" data-editable="">Second Element</span>

<input id="test" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
```

And here is JavaScript with jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function () {

    var $el = $(this);
    var name = $($el).attr('name');
    var value = $($el).text();
    console.log(name);
    var $input = $('<input name="' + name + '" id="' + name + '" value="' + value + '"/>').val($el.text());
    $el.replaceWith($input);

    var save = function () {
        var $p = $('<span data-editable class="pztest" name="' + name + '" id="' + name + '" />').text($input.val());
        $input.replaceWith($p);
    };

    $input.one('blur', save).focus();

});


$("#test").on('click', function(){
    var ok = $("span")
        .map(function () {
        return this.id;
    })
        .get()
        .join();

    var ok2 = $("#" + ok).text();
    alert(ok);
    alert(ok2);
    //return [ok, ok2];
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/3/

I would like to return the results as an array example:

```
{element id : element value}
```

How can I read ids and values only inside specific form so something like:

```
<form id = "editableForm">
<span id="test1">Need these details</span>
<span id="test2">Need these details</span>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<span id="test3">Don't need details of this span</span>
```

Lets say I have got more than 1 form on the page and I want JavaScript to detect which form has been submitted and grab values of these span elements inside the form

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Loop through the spans to populate `ok2` ... https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#test").on('click', function(){
    var result = {};
    $("span").each(function (k, v) {
        result[v.id] = v.innerHTML;
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(result));

    //return [ok, ok2];
});
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/4/

---

Container issue:

You should use this selector: `#editableForm span` if you want to get all the divs inside this container.

```
$("#editableForm span").each(function (k, v) {
    result[v.id] = v.innerHTML;
});
```

But if you want to get only first-level children elements then you should use this selector: `#editableForm > span`

Example with getting all the spans inside `#editableForm` container: https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/9/

---

If you want to have several forms, then you can do like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = {};
    $(this).find('span').each(function (k, v) {
        result[v.id] = v.innerHTML;
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(result));

    //return [ok, ok2];
});
```

Example with two forms: https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/10/

Comment: I really like this answer, its exactly what I wanted, thanks :)

Comment: i have added another part of the question about getting span inside specific form, would you know the answer for that?

Comment: And if I got 2 forms on the page how can I detect which one was submitted and grab only these values?

Comment: For this usecase wrap your code inside $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){....}) and use $(this).find('span') to find only the spans inside this form.

Comment: Thank you very much this answers all my questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.text` to return the value of multiple elements. It doesn't matter how many elements are selected, `.text` will only return the value of the first one.

Virtually all jQuery methods that return a value behave this way.

If you want to get an array of values for an array of matched elements, you need another `map`. You also need to join the strings with `, #` as you're producing something along the lines of `#id1id2id3` instead of `#id1, #id2, #id3`:

```
var ok = $("span").map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).join(', #')

var ok2 = $("#" + ok).map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

That said, you're *already* selecting the right set of elements in your *first map*. You pass over each element to get its ID, you *already have the element*. There is no reason to throw it away and reselect the same thing by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right following code will do the job

```
        var ok = $("span")
            .map(function () {
                  return  {id: $(this).attr('id') ,  value: $(this).text()};
            }).get();
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v427zbo1/8/).